# Solution verification on standard normal random variable.

Tags: probability, random-variables

The problem I am solving is as follows:
A certain IQ examination has a score that is normally distributed with mean $100$ and standard deviation $14.2$. What is the probability that a randomly chosen test taker has an IQ score higher than $130$?

Here's what I did:
$P\{X>130\}=P\{ \frac{X-100}{14.2}>\frac{130-100}{14.2}\}$

$\hspace{5.78cm}=P\{Z>2.11\}=1-\phi(2.11)=1-.98=.02$

Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: this is the right procedure.

Comment: You have got it.